# Classifying space infinite totally ordered set contractible

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

Let $(X,\le)$ be a totally ordered set. Regarding it as a category, it has a classifying space $B(X,\le)=|N_\bullet(X,\le)|$. This should be the (possible infinite) simplex with vertices $X$, hence I expect it to be contractible.

However, I was not able to explicitly proof contractibility starting from the definition $$B(X,\le)=(\coprod_{i\in\mathbb{N}_0}N_i(X,\le)\times\Delta^i)/\tilde{} $$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't really share your intuition. For example, the [long ray](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/long+line) is not contractible, and it seems to me that it is the classifying space of $\omega_1$ (unless I've misunderstood the definition). Cardinality of $X$ seems to play a role here.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi $\omega_1$ has a bottom element, so its nerve is contractible (in the strong sense). More generally, any category with an initial object has contractible nerve.

Comment: Oh, right @ZhenLin. Hm. I guess the long line is the classifying space of $\bar\omega_1 + \omega_1$ (where $\bar\omega_1$ is $\omega_1$ with the reverse order), though, and *that* is not contractible according to the $n$Lab. But I'm not sure which part of the argument is specific to the long line, so I'm not 100% sure that the long line is homotopic to $B(\bar\omega_1 + \omega_1)$...

Comment: Van Kampen theorem? $B(X,\le)$ regarded as a coend, is a coequalizer:
$$\coprod_{m\to n} N_n(X, \le)\times \Delta^m \rightrightarrows \coprod_{n\ge 0} N_n(X, \le)\times \Delta^n \to B(X,\le)$$